# Access to related data of newly created model instance using post_save signal handler

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I need to send an e-mail when new instance of `Entry` model is created via admin panel. So in `models.py` I have:

```
class Entry(models.Model):   
    attachments = models.ManyToManyField(to=Attachment, blank=True)
    #some other fields
    #...
    sent = models.BooleanField(editable=False, default=False)
```

Then I'm registring post_save handler function:

```
def send_message(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.sent:
        #sending an e-mail message containing details about related attachments
        #...
        instance.sent = True
        instance.save()

post_save.connect(send_message, sender=Entry)
```

It works, but as I mentioned before, I also need to access related attachments to include their details in the message. Unfortunatelly `instance.attachments.all()` returns empty list inside `send_message` function even if attachments were actually added.

As I figured out, when the post_save signal is sent, related data of saved model isn't saved yet, so I can't get related attachments from that place.
Question is: am I able to accomplish this using signals, or in any other way, or do I have to put this email sending code outside, for example overriding admin panel change view for `Entry` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by overriding the [save_model()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method on the ModelAdmin.  You could either send your email in there or fire a custom signal which triggers your handler to send the email.

If you have inlines, I believe you need to use [save_formset()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset) instead.

Comment: Thanks. That should be what I need. I'll try to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the [M2M Changed Signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed) instead? This signal is sent when the M2M field is changed.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it. But how exactly could it be used? As you can see, attachments field have blank=True, so there can be a situation, when there's no related attachments at all, and as I suppose, no m2m_changed signal will be sent then. And if I connect m2m_changed signal to my send_message handler, and there will be more than one attachment added, email message will be (as I think) sent multiple times, which is also wrong. So, any ideas of solving this?

Comment: I doubt this can be done with signals. You will have to do this with a custom Django app (not the built-in admin). It's a lot of work, but I don't see a way around it. Basically 1) submit form 2) create object + relations based on what was entered and 3) if successful send email.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use `ModelAdmin` `save_model()` method, as shadfc proposed.
Anyway newly changed related objects aren't accessible from there either. But `save_model` takes filled `form` as a parameter, so I used that. My `send_message` isn't used as a signal handler anymore and I added related_data parameter.

```
def send_message(sender, instance, related_data={}):
    #sending e-mail using related_data parameter to access additional related objects
    #...
```

in `admin.py` I have:

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        send_message(sender=Entry, instance=obj,
                     related_data={'attachments': form.cleaned_data['attachments']} )
```