# Django: Querying M2M table after object creation returns empty array

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm using a Django signal to run a block of code after a model saves using post_save. The signal receiver in post_save gets an instance of the object sends it to a method for some processing before the instance is sent to a third party via network.

One of my models, foo, has a many-to-many relation with another model, bar,  and I need to add an array named bar_id that contains ids of each bar before I send foo to the third party.

This configuration works when updating a foo instance however when I create a new instance of foo and I query for its relations (see the *troublesome query* in the *Add Bar's ID to Foo and send it to third party* section, the query is returning an empty query set even though the relation exists in the database. This exact same query returns a query set if I update the same model moments later.

Any ideas of why this may be happening?

Here's the code:

**Register the signal**

from django.apps import AppConfig

```
class FooConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'foo'

    def ready(self):
        import foo.signals
```

**Signal Code**

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import F
from .models import Foo
from utils import search

def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    table_name = 'foo'
    instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    foo = Foo.objects.filter(id=instance.id).annotate(objectID=F('id')).values()[0]
    if kwargs.get('created', True):
        search.add_object(table_name, foo, instance.id)
    elif not kwargs.get('created', False):
        search.update_object(table_name, foo)

post_save.connect(my_handler, sender=Foo)
```

**Add Bar's ID to Foo and send it to third party**

```
def add_object(table_name, instance, pk):
    from foo.models import Foo

    env = settings.ENVIRONMENT
    # init client
    client = algoliasearch.Client('key', settings.ALGOLIA_KEY)
    # init index that object will be added to
    index = client.init_index(env + "_" + table_name)

    if table_name == 'foo':
        # the troublesome query 
        bar = Foo.bar.through.objects.filter(foo_id=pk)
        instance['bar_id'] = []
        print('pre loop')
        for k in bar:
            print('for loop entered')
            instance['bar_id'].append(k.get('bar_id'))
```

Comment: If the `Foo` instance is new how can there already be entries in the M2M table that point to it? Presumably, whatever you're doing to populate that relation is happening after the signal handler is run. Note that signal handlers in Django are synchronous and happen immediately.

Comment: Yea I think you're right. I've found a similar post that confirms the problem you pointed out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680931/access-to-related-data-of-newly-created-model-instance-using-post-save-signal-ha?rq=1

Comment: You might want to look into [`transaction.on_commit()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit). That seems like a natural place to do things like sending the data to a third party.